# Highcharts Heatmap Legend Max

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

I have a highchart heatmap and I make sure my data is between 0 and 100 (kinda percentage)
However in this case, the heatmap tries to be smart and shows the legend up to 120

I understand why it works this way but in my case it is not really usefull...

Any clue how to avoid this behavior?

For reference I modified slightly the one from the documentation: 
`null`http://jsfiddle.net/tyoqq1fe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's another option to `colorAxis`. [Documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.max)
Make your colorAxis object in options like this:

```
    colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },
```

Full [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnv6jdw6/)

Comment: Wooow, I think I would have never found that out... What a bad name for such a feature... I'll test it right away